# Implementation of a small Database Application in client Computer

Tags: java, database, netbeans-7, embedded-database

I have two questions regarding implementation of a small Database Application generated by me in JAVA using Netbeans 7.2 for school.

1. I am using MS SQL Server 2008 with java using Netbeans 7.2. if i
   will implement my Database Application on my client computer do i
   need to install MS SQL Server 2008 on my client computer for using a
   small Database Application.
2. The database i have created in MS SQL Server 2008 for my a small
   Database Application can i embedded my database file in my
   Database Application using Netbeans 7.2 because the database file i
   have created is on my computer. So how i will implement my a small
   Database Application on my client computer with database file
   without installation MS SQL Server 2008 on my client computer.

My Database Application development tools:

1. Language JAVA
2. IDE Netbeans 7.2
3. Database MS SQL Server 2008
4. Windows 7
5. Jasper iReport

My Database Application Java database connectivity class file source code so how i can convert Java database connectivity source code for embedded database source code because Java Driver Manager using current my computer MS SQL Server 2008 instance name with username and Password.

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Conect {
    Connection conn=null;

    public static Connection Connector()
    {
    try 
        {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://STAR;databaseName=test","me","778899");
        return conn;
        }

         catch (Exception exp)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exp);
            }
        return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Use an embedded database, like Derby, HSQL and others. They can use a file the same way like Access. That needs no Windows installation of MSSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a "desktop" app that needs a database (i.e. it needs to persist a dataset that's not shared between users), use an embedded database engine. For Java, [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) is a good choice.

Comment: Access is also an option, you can download the Access 2007 runtime [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910). Then you can include your .accdb file with your application.

Comment: thanks for reply sir @millimoose .... actually i am doing all these first time means i am beginner level. i have developed a small application for educational institute that stored student record, only for one client computer so can i embedded database in my this application and without installation of MS SQL Server 2008 on my client computer run my database application ?

Comment: @biltong I'm not sure why you would want to do that a) in a Java application, and b) instead of using SQL Server Compact Edition (in a .NET app)

Comment: @SilentHeart If you use an embedded database, you'll have to deploy the library for it with your application, but it's just a simple JAR. Just put it on the CLASSPATH when starting the app. So, to be more precise, you don't need to run the H2 installer on the "client" computer - the installer just sets up some administration tools that are more useful for development.

Comment: thanks for reply sir @millimoose ... i understand your answer and i am very happy to helped me...

Answer (score 1):

1. Probably yes, unless your client can access SQL Server running on a remote machine.
2. NetBeans is an IDE.  It shouldn't have much to do with how you implement and deploy an application.  It's certainly not necessary to deploy an app.  If you rely on it too much, it's likely you'll have issues when it's out of the picture.

If you need a database for a client, you can go with Hypersonic (as recommended by Millimoose) or Derby, which is already part of JDK 7 and higher, or SQLLite.  There are lots of choices for embedded, local database besides SQL Server.  The good news is that your code only needs to change the connection URL and JDBC driver JAR, as long as the SQL is generic enough.

Comment: thanks for reply sir @duffymo .... it means i must need to install MS SQL Server 2008 on my client computer because my client computer is not connected with my computer. also is there no way available to embedded database file in my database application and without installation of MS SQL Server 2008 on my client computer run my database application